# Solving trig functions with specified intervals sympy Python

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, sympy, intervals

I want to `Find the points where y =tan(x) intersects with the graph of y= cos (x) somewhere on the interval 0 < x < /2` where I solve the function between those intervals but the `SolveTrig` function below does not work. It outputs the error `TypeError: cannot create mpf from (x > 0) & (x < pi/2)`. How would I be able to fix it?

```
import mpmath
from IPython.display import display, Latex 
from sympy import *
init_printing(pretty_print=True)

a, b, c, d, x, y, z = symbols('a b c d x y z')

Equation1= input('Enter the first equation: ')
Equation2= input('Enter the second equation: ')

#Itervals 
cond = And(0 < x, x < (pi/2))

SolveTrig = nsolve( Equation1- Equation2 , cond)

[s for s in SolveTrig if cond.subs(s)]
```

Expected Output:

```
0.666 radians
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do there are a few related functions for this:

```
In [3]: solveset(Eq(tan(x), cos(x)), x, Reals)
Out[3]: 
⎧            ⎛     _________⎞ │      ⎫   ⎧            ⎛     _________⎞     │  
⎪            ⎜√2⋅╲╱ -1 + √5 ⎟ │      ⎪   ⎪            ⎜√2⋅╲╱ -1 + √5 ⎟     │  
⎨2⋅n⋅π + atan⎜──────────────⎟ │ n ∊ ℤ⎬ ∪ ⎨2⋅n⋅π - atan⎜──────────────⎟ + π │ n
⎪            ⎝      2       ⎠ │      ⎪   ⎪            ⎝      2       ⎠     │  
⎩                             │      ⎭   ⎩                                 │  

    ⎫
    ⎪
 ∊ ℤ⎬
    ⎪
    ⎭

In [4]: solve(Eq(tan(x), cos(x)), x)
Out[4]: 
⎡                                                                             
⎢      ⎛       _________             ⎞        ⎛     _________             ⎞   
⎢      ⎜  √2⋅╲╱ -1 + √5    ⅈ⋅(1 - √5)⎟        ⎜√2⋅╲╱ -1 + √5    ⅈ⋅(1 - √5)⎟   
⎢-ⅈ⋅log⎜- ────────────── - ──────────⎟, -ⅈ⋅log⎜────────────── - ──────────⎟, -
⎣      ⎝        2              2     ⎠        ⎝      2              2     ⎠   

     ⎛                  _______________⎞        ⎛                  ___________
     ⎜                 ╱             2 ⎟        ⎜                 ╱           
     ⎜  ⅈ⋅(1 + √5)   ╲╱  4 - (1 + √5)  ⎟        ⎜  ⅈ⋅(1 + √5)   ╲╱  4 - (1 + √
ⅈ⋅log⎜- ────────── - ──────────────────⎟, -ⅈ⋅log⎜- ────────── + ──────────────
     ⎝      2                2         ⎠        ⎝      2                2     

____⎞⎤
  2 ⎟⎥
5)  ⎟⎥
────⎟⎥
    ⎠⎦

In [5]: nsolve(Eq(tan(x), cos(x)), x, 0.1)
Out[5]: 0.666239432492515
```